# Create template for our own process

Tags: configuration, gemini

I have signed up to using the Gemini trial and have a few questions.
We develop software that is deployed on computers in the company network.
Our current process follows more traditional waterfall methodology, with steps like:
Gather requirements
Design solution
Develop solution
Test solution
Maintain

I'd like to create a process that includes these steps, i.e it will include some of the features of 
requirements capture and management
testing and QA management
bug & issue tracking

Is it possible to create a template that will combine all of these features in the one project.

Sorry if this is a basic question, I've only got set up and need to get an answer for this question before i start using it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are doing that in our company. We have used the Testing Q & A template and added the extra types we needed (story, task, bug etc...). So you can create test cases and other types in the same project.